# GridView within RecyclerView search filter IndexOutofBounds

Tags: java, android, filter, android-recyclerview, android-gridview

I have a `RecyclerView` with each row containing a grid a variable elements with a category header.
I'm implementing a `SearchView` to filter the list but I keep getting "index out of bounds".

I think the problem is that when I search, the elements(array) passed to the Adapter are for each row and since each row has a different number of elements, at some point the position value contains an old index of some row. I need to filter each row somehow.
I've been tackling this for a while.

Adapter for sections in the `RecyclerView`:

```
public class SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context mContext;
    private static final int SECTION_TYPE = 0;

    private boolean mValid = true;
    private int mSectionResourceId;
    private int mTextResourceId;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mBaseAdapter;
    private SparseArray<Section> mSections = new SparseArray<Section>();
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;


    public SectionedGridRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, int sectionResourceId, int textResourceId,RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                            RecyclerView.Adapter baseAdapter) {

        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mSectionResourceId = sectionResourceId;
        mTextResourceId = textResourceId;
        mBaseAdapter = baseAdapter;
        mContext = context;
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;



        mBaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged() {
                mValid = mBaseAdapter.getItemCount()>0;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                mValid = mBaseAdapter.getItemCount()>0;
                notifyItemRangeChanged(positionStart, itemCount);
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                mValid = mBaseAdapter.getItemCount()>0;
                notifyItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
            }

            @Override
            public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                mValid = mBaseAdapter.getItemCount()>0;
                notifyItemRangeRemoved(positionStart, itemCount);
            }
        });

        final GridLayoutManager layoutManager = (GridLayoutManager)(mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager());
        layoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
            @Override
            public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                return (isSectionHeaderPosition(position))? layoutManager.getSpanCount() : 1 ;
            }
        });
    }


    public static class SectionViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView title;

        public SectionViewHolder(View view, int mTextResourceid) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(mTextResourceid);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int typeView) {
        if (typeView == SECTION_TYPE) {
            final View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(mSectionResourceId, parent, false);

            return new SectionViewHolder(view,mTextResourceId);
        }else{
            return mBaseAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(parent, typeView -1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder sectionViewHolder, int position) {
        if (isSectionHeaderPosition(position)) {
            ((SectionViewHolder)sectionViewHolder).title.setText(mSections.get(position).title);
        }else{
            mBaseAdapter.onBindViewHolder(sectionViewHolder,sectionedPositionToPosition(position));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return isSectionHeaderPosition(position)
                ? SECTION_TYPE
                : mBaseAdapter.getItemViewType(sectionedPositionToPosition(position)) +1 ;
    }


    public static class Section {
        int firstPosition;
        int sectionedPosition;
        CharSequence title;

        public Section(int firstPosition, CharSequence title) {
            this.firstPosition = firstPosition;
            this.title = title;
        }

        public CharSequence getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    }


    public void setSections(Section[] sections) {
        mSections.clear();

        Arrays.sort(sections, new Comparator<Section>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Section o, Section o1) {
                return (o.firstPosition == o1.firstPosition)
                        ? 0
                        : ((o.firstPosition < o1.firstPosition) ? -1 : 1);
            }
        });

        int offset = 0; // offset positions for the headers we're adding
        for (Section section : sections) {
            section.sectionedPosition = section.firstPosition + offset;
            mSections.append(section.sectionedPosition, section);
            ++offset;
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int positionToSectionedPosition(int position) {
        int offset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mSections.size(); i++) {
            if (mSections.valueAt(i).firstPosition > position) {
                break;
            }
            ++offset;
        }
        return position + offset;
    }

    public int sectionedPositionToPosition(int sectionedPosition) {
        if (isSectionHeaderPosition(sectionedPosition)) {
            return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
        }

        int offset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mSections.size(); i++) {
            if (mSections.valueAt(i).sectionedPosition > sectionedPosition) {
                break;
            }
            --offset;
        }
        return sectionedPosition + offset;
    }

    public boolean isSectionHeaderPosition(int position) {
        return mSections.get(position) != null;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return isSectionHeaderPosition(position)
                ? Integer.MAX_VALUE - mSections.indexOfKey(position)
                : mBaseAdapter.getItemId(sectionedPositionToPosition(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mValid ? mBaseAdapter.getItemCount() + mSections.size() : 0);
    }

}
```

Adapter for each row:

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleAdapter.SimpleViewHolder> {


    private final Context mContext;
    private List<Activity> mItems;
    private int mCurrentItemId = 0;
    int poz;


    public static class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final TextView title;
        public final ImageView image;

        public SimpleViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
        }
    }

    public SimpleAdapter(Context context, List<Activity> activities) {
        mContext = context;
        mItems = activities;

    }

    public SimpleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new SimpleViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleViewHolder holder,  int position) {
        poz = position;
        holder.title.setText(mItems.get(position).getName());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mItems.get(position).getImage_url()).into(holder.image);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("Activity", mItems.get(poz).getName() + " Clicked");
            }
        });


    }


    public void addItem(int position) {
        final int id = mCurrentItemId++;
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return  mItems.size();
    }



    //new stuff

    public void setModels(List<Activity> models) {
        mItems = new ArrayList<>(models);
    }



    public Activity removeItem(int position) {
        final Activity model = mItems.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        return model;
    }

    public void addItem(int position, Activity model) {
        mItems.add(position, model);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void moveItem(int fromPosition, int toPosition) {
        final Activity model = mItems.remove(fromPosition);
        mItems.add(toPosition, model);
        notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);
    }


    public void animateTo(List<Activity> models) {
        applyAndAnimateRemovals(models);
        applyAndAnimateAdditions(models);
        applyAndAnimateMovedItems(models);
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateRemovals(List<Activity> newModels) {
        for (int i = mItems.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            final Activity model = mItems.get(i);
            if (!newModels.contains(model)) {
                removeItem(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void applyAndAnimateAdditions(List<Activity> newModels) {
        for (int i = 0, count = newModels.size(); i < count; i++) {
            final Activity model = newModels.get(i);
            if (!mItems.contains(model)) {
                addItem(i, model);
            }
        }
    }



    private void applyAndAnimateMovedItems(List<Activity> newModels) {
        for (int toPosition = newModels.size() - 1; toPosition >= 0; toPosition--) {
            final Activity model = newModels.get(toPosition);
            final int fromPosition = mItems.indexOf(model);
            if (fromPosition >= 0 && fromPosition != toPosition) {
                moveItem(fromPosition, toPosition);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_activities, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.activities_search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();


    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {

            s = s.toLowerCase();

            final List<Activity> filteredModelList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Activity model : activities) {
                final String text = model.getName().toLowerCase();
                if (text.contains(s)) {
                    filteredModelList.add(model);
                }
            }
            ((SimpleAdapter)mSimpleAdapter).animateTo(filteredModelList);
            mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(0);
            return true;
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```